# Laravel 5.4 is not setting cookies when uploaded to server

Tags: php, cookies, laravel-5

I am facing this issue since last 2 days, tried many things but not able to get it working, I am getting most annoying `tokenMismatchException`exception.

I tried a fresh installation that works fine, so I copied `vendor` folder from working on to my actual app, but it didn't work. After more digging, I saw that `laravel_session` & `XSRF-TOKEN` cookies are not set in chrome dev tool.

What could be the reason, it's working on localhost but not working on the server.

**Main problem what I see it not able to set the cookies**

Session storage is working as I can see on server `storage/framework/session/` creates new file on refresh. So it's not permission error.

Laravel Framework 5.4.16

**.env**

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:7WcmnZI8WcYQiNr9jn3JcTf//1scVAPtz2crL0bz4TE=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=sqlite

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

**app/session.php**

```
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,
];
```

Same settings works on fresh install.

Comment: facing same problem

Comment: I replaced my config directory with freshly installed one which fixed it for me. read here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/servers/laravel-54-is-not-setting-cookies-when-uploaded-to-server

Comment: My issue was one of my PHP files have space at start before PHP opening tag.